# Find all prime factors of a given number

Tags: c, prime-factoring

I want to find [all prime factors of a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization), for example `8: 2   2   2` or `12: 2   2   3`.

So I write this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, triangularNum, n;

    scanf("%d", &triangularNum);

    for (a = 2; a <= n; ++a) {
        while (n % a == 0) {
            n = triangularNum;
            printf("%d\t", a);
            n = n / a;
        }
    }
}
```

But when it has a factor with power > 1, it only prints that factor many times.

Comment: You realize that the first time around, `n` is still undefined?

Comment: Use a debugger. Step through your execution.

Comment: `n = n/a;` has no effect, because you immediately do `n=triangularNum` the next time through the loop.

Comment: You should do that initialization of `n` at the very beginning.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works just fine if you remove this `triangularNum`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a, n;
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (a=2; a<=n; ++a)
  {
    while(n%a==0)
    {
      printf("%d\t", a);
      n = n/a;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code finds all prime factors of a given number much faster.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int a, n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  
  int sqroot = (int)sqrt(n);
  
  while (n % 2 == 0)
  {
    n = n / 2;
    printf("%d\t", 2);
  }
  
  for (a=3; a<=sqroot; a+=2)
  {
    while(n%a==0)
    {
      printf("%d\t", a);
      n = n/a;
    }
  }
}
```

The most basic method of checking the primality of a given integer n is called trial division. This method divides n by each integer from 2 up to the square root of n. Any such integer dividing n evenly establishes n as composite; otherwise, it is prime. Integers larger than the square root do not need to be checked because, whenever n = a ⋅ b, one of the two factors a and b is less than or equal to the square root of n. Another optimization is to check only primes as factors in this range. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This method needs an edge case to check if n is still larger than 2 at the end. In this case, n is a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

```
 void factor(int n){
   if(n<=1) return;
   while(n%2==0){
      printf("2 ");
      n=n/2;  
   }
   while(n%3==0){
       printf("3 ");
       n=n/3;
   }
   for(int i=5;i*i<=n;i=i+6){
       while(n%i==0){
           printf("%d\t",i);
           n=n/i;
       }
       while(n%(i+2)==0){
           printf("%d\t",(i+2));
           n=n/(i+2);
       }
   }
   if(n>3)
    printf("%d\t",n);
```

}

Worst case Time complexity: O(sqrt(n))